# How do I change the language to English in Dungeon Defenders?

Tags: dungeon-defenders

So, Dungeon Defenders' localization is really not very good at all. Google Translate quality, in fact. In addition, it seems to completely ignore my default Steam preference of English.

How can I change the game's language to English? Usually, you can select the language via Steam, or at least a game option, but Dungeon Defenders seems to offer neither.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change the language by going in to the configuration option, while starting the game.

[image]

If you start the game via Steam, a splash screen should popup congaing a "Configure" button. Press that, and it will take you to the configuration option.

If the splash screen doesn't popup, you can navigate to "`\Steam\steamapps\common\dungeon defenders\Binaries\DunDefConfig.exe`", and launch the config from there.
For the non-steam users navigate to "`<Installation path>\dungeon defenders\Binaries\DunDefConfig.exe`"

Comment: Oh, there's a configure option *when starting the game*. I looked through the Steam settings, in-game settings, and even the .ini files, but I completely missed *that*.

Comment: Do you know how one would go about changing the language if not using steam?

Comment: @oadams For the non-steam users navigate to "<Installation path>\dungeon defenders\Binaries\DunDefConfig.exe"